# Why doesn't this sqlite query in a nested for loop return more than 1 result?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite

anyone could please help me figure this out? I am new to Swift and sqlite.

I am passing this  string to a function

```
let compositionstring = "iris, magenta, iris";
```

Where I convert it to an array with

```
let compositionArr = string.components(separatedBy: ",")
```

Then I am expecting the following code to query a database and print the path, filename, and category for each in compositionstring.

```
       do {
        try compositionArr.forEach {
            print($0)
            
            for var files in try db.prepare(files.select(path, name, category).filter(category.like($0)).limit(1)) {
                print("path: \(files[path]), filename: \(files[name]), category: \(files[category])")

            }

        }
```

But I only get the first result, and nothing after.

iris

path: file://localhost/Volumes/IWL%20Jen%20Vid/IWL%20Captions/Material_Sonia/Sonia%202019/IWL%20videos/Mexico/Palacio%20belle%20arte/IMG_7762.MOV, filename: IMG_7762.MOV, category: Iris

magenta

iris

There must be something very basic I am missing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason may be that there is no matching for the other items so for loop doesn't run as of empty result from  `db.prepare......`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but its not it. If I manually enter the 2nd entry from the array and run it, I do get a result.

path: file://localhost/Volumes/IWL%20Jen%20Vid/IWL%20Captions/Material_Bernhard/Bernhard%20June%202018/IMG_1968.MOV, filename: IMG_1968.MOV, category: Magenta
 magenta

Comment: from your string there is a space `-magenta` not `magenta` ? can you try it also separately and see ?

Comment: Yes, thats the solution! Thank you Sh_Khan